# VSCode crashes when starting up in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I changed my workspace to Ubuntu recently, and I encountered the crashing problem.

The vscode was installed by apt. And it could be open for a few seconds, then it crashes automatically.

I tried to figure it out with the `code --verbose` command. It shows

```
[67802:0311/205929.505928:INFO:CONSOLE(626)] "%cTRACE color: #888 [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] /home/chou/.config/Code/logs/20210311T205927/telemetry.log", source: file:///usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js (626)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
/dev/fd/3: No such file or directory
Server response:
[67849:0311/205929.809879:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(40)] Recvmsg error: Connection reset by peer (104)
```

The last line might be caused by the ssh-extension, so I have removed it manually from `~/.vscode/extensions`.

But the problem still exists, I've also tried with the `--disable-extension` flag, but nothing changed.

The only way I can enter vscode now is by `sudo code --usr-data-dir` command. I wonder what would cause this kind of frustrating problem.

EDIT:
Here's the last few lines of `exthost.log` file:

```
[2021-03-11 22:07:54.814] [exthost] [debug] ProxyResolver#resolveProxy cached https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/api/profiles/AIF-d9b70cd4-b9f9-4d70-929b-a071c400b217/appId DIRECT 
Error: Error for stack trace
    at Pe (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:96:3)
    at ProxyAgent.addRequest (/usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar/vscode-proxy-agent/index.js:73:16)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:296:16)
    at Object.request (https.js:314:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar/agent-base/patch-core.js:23:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar/https-proxy-agent/node_modules/agent-base/patch-core.js:25:22)
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar/socks-proxy-agent/node_modules/agent-base/patch-core.js:23:20
    at Object.U [as request] (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:96:4165)
    at Function.e.makeRequest (/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/github-authentication/dist/extension.js:1:7505)
    at Timeout.s [as _onTimeout] (/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/github-authentication/dist/extension.js:1:17133)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
[2021-03-11 22:07:55.351] [exthost] [info] extension host terminating: parent process 82934 does not exist anymore: kill ESRCH (code: ESRCH) (errno: ESRCH)
[2021-03-11 22:07:56.368] [exthost] [info] exiting with code 0
```

It seems like it may be the problem of the proxy resolver. But I still have no idea of how to fixed it up...

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing. I wish that I had an answer... Please let me know if you find out how to fix it.
One thing that I do know - I was able to run the snap of VS Code, but the snap is ... an old version, and kinda goofy. It's not updated often (like most MS products on the snapstore.)

Comment: I'm afraid I still have no answer to this. But I changed too insiders version instead, it could be run normally as before. By the way, I was unable to run the snap version of vscode either. Hope this will help you. ;)

Comment: I got 1.54.3 to work last night. I grabbed it directly from the snapstore. To get it to work, I had to uninstall it, remove the snap saves, and delete all of the VSCode directories out of my user profile. I was then able to sync things and get the installed extensions/settings back. So, for now it works, but I fear when they make a new release :P... And thank you, your response sent me into the direction that got things working. There was some setting or something in it that was causing the glitch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was experiencing the same issue. I'm using Pop OS 20.04 LTS and Visual Studio Code would crash after startup. It seems the problem might be related to mixing the `.snap` package installation with the `.deb` package. This github comment has a solution that worked for me:
(https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/118727#issuecomment-801847011)

I had to remove the `vscodevscode.github-authentication/github.auth` entry from the `Passwords and Keys` app.

Comment: Wow that really works. After deleting the authentication in 'password and keys', and reinstall 'deb' version again. It does run normally. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No problem glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

If you Install VSCode and its crash when startup According to Github just Reboot your system.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to open an Ipython notebook in VSCode and mine kept crashing because I had too many plots in the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

for kali linux or oher debian `sudo apt purge code-oss` remove the existing VSCode:

```bash
  sudo apt-get install wget gpg
  wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg - dearmor > packages.microsoft.gpg
  sudo install -D -o root -g root -m 644 packages.microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg
  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
  rm -f packages.microsoft.gpg
```

then:

```bash
  sudo apt install apt-transport-https
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install code # or code-insiders
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).